# Best way to draw on iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, quartz-2d

I am making a math drawing app on ipad. Users can manipulate the obejects on the screen like quadratic curve or sin curve. To update all objects on the screen, I need to redraw the whole screen at 60 fps, which costs lots of time. I currently implement drawing with Quartz2D, but the performance is bad when there are many objects on the screen. I heard that directly using openGL ES is better, because it use GPU to draw. But I am wondering how to draw cubic or quadratic curve with openGL ES. Or, is there other better choice to improve the drawing?

Answer (score 0):

The openGL should be quite good at doing this but the curves are not just out of the box. Assuming you find some sample or create one from the scratch till the point you can draw some shapes there may be quite a few procedures accomplishing this.

The most direct one would be to create lines from points with specific resolution. That would mean when having function `f(x)` simply iterate `x` through the resolution. Say you are seeing the curve on interval `[a, b]` and want a resolution of `R` intervals that would produce the loop `for(float x=a; x<=b; x+=(b-a)/R)`. Now just draw this as a line strip. In most cases the resolution can be quite high and you will have a nice result but there are cases where this will not work, the steep functions or some alternating functions will be missing some points. A problematic kind are for instance `sin(x*some_large_factor)`.

Using the same procedure it might work better if you could transform the function to be dependent on the curve length instead of the `X`. This procedure would also be able to draw curves such as circles.

Another way is injecting a function into the shader and checking if the point is near enough the function. You will receive the `x` and `y` positions which you may insert into your function and check their distance in a way `if(abs(y-f(x)) < lineWidth) // do draw`. This procedure will be totally accurate but the problem is now the line width is defined by `Y` which will make the steep parts of the curve appear thicker. If you are able to find the true distance to the curve (the nearest point on the curve) this would work perfectly...

Have you tried finding some library or some open source to draw the curve in openGL though?

Comment: I try to use cocos2d, but it seems not having related function.

Comment: I do not think cocos2D is in any way a proper tool to draw curves.